# Android Not getting the correct boolean

Tags: java, android, sockets

im with a problem with some java logic..

Im creating an app that uses Socket IO, but i have a problem with my boolean value.

The code

MainActivity.class

```
package packname.shutdownpc;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ImageView Switch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.mSocket.on("state", controller.checkState);
        controller.mSocket.connect();


        Boolean isOn = controller.isOn(); //This isnt working
        Log.d("Main Activity Condition", Boolean.toString(isOn)); //This isnt Working

        Switch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if(isOn) //This is always false because that isnt working..
            Switch.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.switch_green, null));
        else
            Switch.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.switch_red, null));


    }

}
```

Controller.class

```
package packname.shutdownpc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;;
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


/**
 * Created by IvoMi on 14/11/2015.
 */
public class Controller extends Activity {

    public boolean isOn;


    public Socket mSocket; {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://**.**.*.***:8080/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }


    public Emitter.Listener checkState = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {

            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            String status;

            try {
                status = data.getString("status");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return;
            }

            Log.d("Text", status); //Its working
            if(status.equals("online")) { //This if is working
                isOn = true;
                Log.d("CONDIDITON", "ITS WORKING");
                Log.d("BOOLEAN", Boolean.toString(isOn));
            }


        }
    };


    public boolean isOn() {
        boolean isOnline;
        isOnline = isOn;

        return isOnline;
    }

}
```

So, i know that my socket io its working.. i did some debugs to check it, i will show them

```
11-14 12:03:55.633 9991-10018/? D/Text: online
11-14 12:03:55.633 9991-10018/? D/CONDIDITON: ITS WORKING
11-14 12:03:55.633 9991-10018/? D/BOOLEAN: true
```

This is the code that sends the "online" to the client (server.js)

```
client.emit("state", {status: "online"});
```

My problem is when i open the app it needs to show the green image, because i set the isOn value to true when i receive the "online" string via socket..

But im doing something wrong because isnt working, i hope u guys understand the problem and thank you all

Comment: It probably doesn't help that your member variable `isOn` is named the exact same as your method `isOn`

Comment: you right, i changed already, but isnt working tho :c

Comment: Why does `Controller` extend `Activity`?

Comment: From the description at the end it sounds like you need to implement a promise as the activity will load well before the network stack completes its call.

Comment: i extended because my old code was using it, but its to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have a race condition where your checkState's call method is called after controller.isOn() is executed. If that turns out to be the case, you might want to set up a listener in the MainActivity that is called back by checkState's call method at the end.

As a side note, are you sure you want Controller to extend an Activity?

Kaamel